# How to disable Ctrl Alt M in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

When in a Java editor in Eclipse, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> inserts a new line (like hitting the enter key). How can I disable that? I did not find any corresponding entry in **Preferences** > **General** > **Keys**.

The same happens if I press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (generally, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> seems to be the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> in many cases).

Is there some other place where you can see/disable/change key shortcuts in Eclipse (or plug-ins?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it unbinds when binding it to another command (for example, maven install) when in Windows.

Comment: That works great, thank you! I chose `Activate Editor` (using `Copy Command` because it already has F12 assigned which I wanted to keep), so it does not do anything undesired if executed.

Answer (score 3):

@msa, Go to : Window --> Preferences --> General --> Keys. Now type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in the search box. You will find a command named as "Add Memory Block" & an option below that "Unbind Command". Select the command & press the button. Now Click on "Apply" button & you're done.

Comment: I saw this entry already but it does not seem to have anything to do with the new line inserted when in the Java editor. That shortcut there only applies for the 'Memory View'. Anyway, I tried disabling that one, but - as expected - with no effect :-(

Answer (score 1):

As stated by RAS, you can unbind the key combination functionality through eclipse **preferences** - > **General** -> **Keys** . Here's a screenshot for easy reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but as commented in RAS answer this does not work, as this key binding is only for the memory view and does something different than inserting a newline. ... or did this work for you?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem for my ctrl+up binding now... Did you find a way to solve this already?